# Access custom request headers node express

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, request

I am building a web api with Express and have not found information on accessing incoming custom request headers.

I will be expecting, for instance, that an incoming post request have a provider_identifier header.  When I receive the request, I need to access that header information to validate their subscription.

Can someone point me in the right direction/provide advice on this?

```
router.post('myendpoint/', function(req, res){
    var providerId = req.????;
});
```

Comment: how did you set the custom header on the client side? I am confused on this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Answering my own question here... was kindof a DUH moment for me.

Using above example, simply reference the headers collection like so:

```
var providerId = req.headers.provider_identifier;
```

One note:  Use an underscore rather than a dash.  "provider-identifier" doesn't work, but "provider_identifier" does.

Comment: If you have a header `provider-identifier`, you should be able to access it via `req.headers['provider-identifier']` (unless Express changes the dash into an underscore).

Comment: Yes... I figured that out just now.  Thanks!

Comment: some time req.headers['provider-identifier'] coming undefined, What could be problem? some time its coming proper :(

Comment: getting undefined too, even if i hardcode the custom req header. What can be wrong?

Comment: I know it's old subject here but what i just noticed in latest express it automatically converts uppercase custom properties to lower case somehow. For whomever lands on this post.